# Google Colab find max value in a dictionary - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: string, dictionary, typeerror, google-colaboratory

It may sound strange but when I try to run the following code in Google Colab to find the maximum value of a dictionary:

`a_dictionary = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}`

`max_key = max(a_dictionary, key=a_dictionary.get)`

`print(max_key)`

I get the following error:
"TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

But that code works perfectly fine on my local Spyder.
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: that code worked for me at google colab, check your colab's python version.

Comment: Thank you! Very strange. It now works for me as well. Thanks anyways!